# Preserve formatting when exporting from Wordpress

Tags: craft3, import, plugin-feedme

I'm using the WP All Export plugin to get posts out of Wordpress, and Feed Me to import to Craft 3. Problem I'm having is I can get a great XML feed out of the WP All Export plugin, but post "Content" fields lose formatting so all comes out as one blob – no paragraph tags etc... Anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Does your XML contain valid HTML or does it contain plain text from the beginning? Are you using a `Redactor` field in Craft or a `Text` field?

Comment: Hi Robin. In the XML some posts contain HTML, some don't. Although far as I can see all posts in WP are formatted right. Importing into a Text field.

Comment: You need a `Redactor` field, Text fields don't parse HTML. Please change the field type and tell me if it works then

Comment: Wow, did not know that. Will try again thanks.

Comment: Wait, it is a Redactor field sorry. Something must be up with the export.

Comment: Okay, so looks like all that's needed is to save each entry and formatting corrects itself.

Answer (score 3):

Just needed to save each entry and formatting corrects itself.